# Xamarin Forms Could not load type Plugin.SharedTransitions.SharedTransitionShell while decoding custom attribute: (null) occurred

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I develop a mobile app on Xamarin forms using visual studio.

I am using Xamarin forms 4.5+ and Android 9.0- API 28.

I am using Panacake view and shared transions when I run my app I get this error below:

Unhandled Exception:

`System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type Plugin.SharedTransitions.SharedTransitionShell while decoding custom attribute: (null) occurred`

Comment: I test with Xamarin.Forms version.4.8.0.1560, Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView 2.3.0.759 and Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions 2.4.0, My target Framework set it to Android 9.0. it could run normally.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thanks it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `Xamarin.Forms version.4.8.0.1560`, `Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView 2.3.0.759` and `Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions 2.4.0`, My target Framework set it to `Android 9.0`. it could run normally.